# how to insert line between points

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, openlayers

Hello i am adding my json data in map as it is show in the code below.
Now i want to insert line between points. I have looking for something similar but without success. i have a other too when i change my data the points in the map dose not update it show only the first data which it has taken at the beginning. IF it exist a way pleas leave your answer.

```
 geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
          styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
              "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
              pointRadius: 2,
              fillColor: "red",
              fillOpacity: 1,
              strokeColor: "black",
              strokeWidth: 0.1,
              strokeOpacity: 1 } ),
              "select": { fillColor: "#8aeeef",
              strokeColor: "#32a8a9",
              labelYOffset:13,
              label:"${name}"} //Text entspricht feature.attributes.name
          }),
          projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
          strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
          protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
              url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gw97c',
              //url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/sqri8',
              format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()

          })
      });
      map.addLayer(geojson_layer); 




I am using a function like this to make a api call. 
HTML:
 <h:commandButton style= "width:120px; height:100px; padding-left:50px;" partialSubmit="true" immediate="true"  onclick="loadDoc()" image="/imgs_box/start.png" ></h:commandButton>
JS:
    function loadDoc() {
                var urlFielda = document.getElementById('urla');
                var urlFieldb = document.getElementById('urlb');
                var urlFieldc = document.getElementById('urlc');
                var urlFieldd = document.getElementById('urld');
               alert("filloi");
               fetch('http://apiexample.org/api/startgetpoint=' + urlFielda.value + '&start1=' + urlFieldb.value + '&end1=' + urlFieldc.value + '&end2='+ urlFieldd.value + '&NaviMethod=1&AllowedAreas=7')
               .then(function(response) {


                   return response.json();
                  // var convertedResponse = convertFormat(response);
                //return convertedResponse.json();
               })
               .then(function(myJson) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
                alert(JSON.stringify(myJson));
               });
             };
```

And i get a response like this: "Waypoints":[{"Lon":19.455128,"Lat":41.310575},{"Lon":19.455128,"Lat":41.310574},{"Lon":19.457388,"Lat":41.300442},{"Lon":19.413507,"Lat":41.295189},{"Lon":16.871931,"Lat":41.175926},
It is possible to convert this json data in geojson and show in the map as the my first ask but getting data from this response not from this url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/sqri8',

I am sorry that i am asking you again for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a line between your points works for me.  Possibly the data hadn't loaded before you attempted to add the line (I used a timeout to wait 2 seconds), or maybe the 0.1 stroke width in the stylemap made the line very difficult to see.  I used `{}` as style for the linestring to override that and use the OpenLayers default.

```js
  var map, layer;
  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
  layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM Map");
  map.addLayer(layer);
  map.setCenter(
      new OpenLayers.LonLat(19.455128, 41.310575).transform(
          new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
          map.getProjectionObject()
      ), 8
  );   

  geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
      styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
          "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
          pointRadius: 2,
          fillColor: "red",
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeColor: "black",
          strokeWidth: 0.1,
          strokeOpacity: 1 } ),
          "select": { fillColor: "#8aeeef",
          strokeColor: "#32a8a9",
          labelYOffset:13,
          label:"${name}"} //Text entspricht feature.attributes.name
      }),
      projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
      strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
      protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
          url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gw97c',
          //url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/sqri8',
          format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
      })
  });
  map.addLayer(geojson_layer); 
 
  setTimeout(function() {
       var points = [];
       geojson_layer.features.forEach(function(feature) { points.push(feature.geometry); });
       geojson_layer.addFeatures([
           new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points), {}, {})
       ]);
  }, 2000);
```

```css
html, body, #map, #background { height: 100%; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

For your other json you would need to loop through the waypoints to build features from the data and add them to the layer yourself, and you could build the linestring at the same time.  The layer wouldn't need strategies or protocol.

```
var features = [];
var points = [];
myJson.Waypoints.forEach(function(wp) {
   var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(wp.Lon, wp.Lat).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
   );
   features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point));
   points.push(point);
}
features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points), {}, {}));
geojson_layer.addFeatures(features);
```

Comment: yes now it works thank you but i do not want to insert the line between  first point and last point but between each point.

Comment: Hi Mike can i ask for something more please.

Comment: I will update my question if it is possible please take a look.

Comment: how can i get myjson from fetch response to use in this function.? i will try something and i will post again. thank you

Comment: `return JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: Thank you mike it works as i wanted. I am very grateful to you. Now i will post the code to help others too.

Answer (score 0):

```
.then(function(myJson) {
 geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
      styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
          "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
          pointRadius: 2,
          fillColor: "red",
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeColor: "black",
          strokeWidth: 0.1,
          strokeOpacity: 1 } ),
          "select": { fillColor: "#8aeeef",
          strokeColor: "#32a8a9",
          labelYOffset:13,
          label:"${name}"} //Text entspricht feature.attributes.name
      }),
      //projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
      //strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
      //protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
         // url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gw97c',
          //url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/sqri8',
          //format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
     // })
  });
  map.addLayer(geojson_layer); 

  //setTimeout(function() {
      //var points = [];
      //geojson_layer.features.forEach(function(feature) { points.push(feature.geometry); });
       //geojson_layer.addFeatures([
           //new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points), {}, {})
       //]);
 //}, 5000);
 var features = [];
var points = [];
myJson.Waypoints.forEach(function(wp) {
   var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(wp.Lon, wp.Lat).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
   );
   features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point));
   points.push(point);
})
features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points), {}, {}));
geojson_layer.addFeatures(features);

            console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
            alert(JSON.stringify(myJson));
           });
         }
```